# Sum of values from nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have this nested dictionary:

```
{'rekless': {'C': 2.0, 'H': 4.0, 'J': 0.0}, 'bwipo': {'C': 3.0, 'D': 4.0, 'H': 0.0}, 'wunder': {'D': 10.0, 'G': 20.0, 'H': 0.50}, 'caps': {'D': 3.1, 'I': 2.0, '9J': 1.0, '10K': 2.0}, 'jankos': {'D': 3.2, 'I': 2.0, 'J': 1.0, 'K': 2.0} }
```

Want i want to do is to loop through it and sum all values of the "C, H, J,", etc...
So like, 'C' is going to be (2.0 + 3.0), 'D' is going to be (4.0 + 10.0 + 3.1 + 3.2).

So i can end up with something similar to this:

```
{ C: 'sum of values from c', D: 'sum of values from d', etc.. }
```

It doesnt need to be in a dictionary the final result.

Any ideias on how to start?

Comment: You'll need to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?, strating point is loop through the dictionary

Comment: Is your "nested dictionary" always two levels as you've shown in your example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through both dictionary and subdictionary:

```
d = {
    'rekless': {'C': 2.0, 'H': 4.0, 'J': 0.0},
    'bwipo': {'C': 3.0, 'D': 4.0, 'H': 0.0},
    'wunder': {'D': 10.0, 'G': 20.0, 'H': 0.50},
    'caps': {'D': 3.1, 'I': 2.0, '9J': 1.0, '10K': 2.0},
    'jankos': {'D': 3.2, 'I': 2.0, 'J': 1.0, 'K': 2.0}
}

summary = dict()
for key, subdict in d.items():
    for k, v in subdict.items():
        summary[k] = summary.get(k, 0) + v

print(summary)
```

Comment: Maybe loop over `.values()` since you don't want the `key`

Comment: @PedroMaia for the first loop, sure, it can be changed to .values() as well, but in the second loop keys are needed

Answer (score 0):

Assume d is:

```
d = {'rekless': {'C': 2.0, 'H': 4.0, 'J': 0.0}, 'bwipo': {'C': 3.0, 'D': 4.0, 'H': 0.0}, 'wunder': {'D': 10.0, 'G': 20.0, 'H': 0.50}, 'caps': {'D': 3.1, 'I': 2.0, '9J': 1.0, '10K': 2.0}, 'jankos': {'D': 3.2, 'I': 2.0, 'J': 1.0, 'K': 2.0} }
```

Try this:

```
vals ={}
for k in d:
    sum_ = 0
    for k_ in d[k]:
        if k_ in vals:
            vals[k_]+= int(d[k][k_])
        else:
            vals[k_]= int(d[k][k_])
for k__ in vals:
    vals[k__]='sum of values from {} is: {}'.format(k__, vals[k__])
```

which results in `vals` to be:

```
{'C': 'sum of values from C is: 5',
 'H': 'sum of values from H is: 4',
 'J': 'sum of values from J is: 1',
 'D': 'sum of values from D is: 20',
 'G': 'sum of values from G is: 20',
 'I': 'sum of values from I is: 4',
 '9J': 'sum of values from 9J is: 1',
 '10K': 'sum of values from 10K is: 2',
 'K': 'sum of values from K is: 2'}
```